# How to run test cases in parallel in TestNG?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a set of TestNG test cases which I want to run parallelly.
I am not using  TestNG suite XML file.

According to http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Running_tests_in_parallel ,
I can specify parallel and threadCount parameter in surefire configuration in the project POM file.

But this is not working. 
The test cases are still running sequentially.

Can I run the test cases in parallel without using the suite XML file ?

Surefire plugin version - 2.21.0
TestNG version - 6.8.21

I have used the following lines in my surefire configuration in POM file

```
<parallel>classes</parallel>                     
<useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
```

Comment: It would help to run your TestNG tests with the latest version `6.14.3` to rule out compatibility issues. The one you are using is more than 3 years old.

Also, picking the right plugin for the type of tests you run helps. So, if in case you are exercising integration tests, `maven-failsafe-plugin` would be a better choice.

Pasting relevant sections of your pom.xml may provide more insight for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run the test `methods / classes` in parallel (i.e. without using suite xml) using `maven-surefire-plugin`.

If you would like to run the test **methods** in parallel, please use the below configuration.

```
<configuration>
    <parallel>methods</parallel>
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
</configuration>
```

If you would like to run the test **classes** in parallel, please use the below configuration.

```
<configuration>
    <parallel>classes</parallel>
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
</configuration>
```

**Run the Maven command:-**

```
mvn clean test
```

**To check whether the test methods are running in different thread and started at the same time:-**

Please add the below `sysout` to observe the behavior. You can comment out or remove the `sysout` later. This is just to understand the behavior.

```
System.out.println("thread id:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "Timestamp :" + LocalDateTime.now());
```

You can clone this [repo](https://github.com/notionquest/testngparallel) and run the above maven command to check the result.

Comment: Can I specify which classes I want to run in parallel mode apart from the rest?